# IOS facebook login using Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, facebook

I have followed the instructions to integrate Facebook login in iOS from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/). It worked initially and I was able to login but then it started showing a blank white screen in safari browser(I'm testing it on simulator). I have cleared the cache and and also unblock the cookies.Please help if anyone knows the solution.

Below is the code that I used in loginViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePictureView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"]];
    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 5);
    loginView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
// This method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
    self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
}
// Logged-in user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.statusLabel.text = @"You're logged in as";
}
// Logged-out user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    self.profilePictureView.profileID = nil;
    self.nameLabel.text = @"";
    self.statusLabel.text= @"You're not logged in!";
}
// Handle possible errors that can occur during login
- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;

    // If the user should perform an action outside of you app to recover,
    // the SDK will provide a message for the user, you just need to surface it.
    // This conveniently handles cases like Facebook password change or unverified Facebook accounts.
    if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error]) {
        alertTitle = @"Facebook error";
        alertMessage = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];

        // This code will handle session closures that happen outside of the app
        // You can take a look at our error handling guide to know more about it
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
        alertTitle = @"Session Error";
        alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";

        // If the user has cancelled a login, we will do nothing.
        // You can also choose to show the user a message if cancelling login will result in
        // the user not being able to complete a task they had initiated in your app
        // (like accessing FB-stored information or posting to Facebook)
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login");

        // For simplicity, this sample handles other errors with a generic message
        // You can checkout our error handling guide for more detailed information
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else {
        alertTitle  = @"Something went wrong";
        alertMessage = @"Please try again later.";
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
    }

    if (alertMessage) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: You are searching for a magic solution: does it returns error/warning/something else?

Comment: no error/warning/something else :(

Comment: show some code snippet please? have you added your url schemes to your app under the info section in projects

Comment: Yes I have added the url schemes with fb(AppID), Facebook App ID and Facebook display name.